# Why is F# type inference not working in this case

Tags: f#

In following case

```
let a = [1]
let f x = x
let b = a |> List.map f
```

a is an int list. We call List.map so for sure f must be a  int->? function. Why is f still typed as 'a ->'a instead of int->int?
If this is how type inference (not)works in F# i see little benefits for it.

Is there an workaround without specifying the type for x in f explicitly?
Lets imagine x has type (A*B*C list ( D option, E list)))

Also another interesting thing:

```
open System.Collections.Generic

let d = new Dictionary()
d.[1] ="a"
```

This does not work unless the "new" keyword is removed.

Comment: It would probably help if you explain why you consider it not working when F# does not restrict the type of `f` needlessly.

Comment: This looks like two questions. You get the best answers here on Stack Overflow if you post two different questions as two different question posts.

Comment: For the second one, you are missing the generic types, and `=` doesn't do what you think it does (it only does comparison, not assignment)

Comment: -1 Please split the question. I would ordinarily read the answers but they can't adhere to the SRP :) Yes, maybe I'm too late and the ship has sailed....

Answer (score 4):

Type inferencing works just fine here. `f` is inferred as having the type `'a -> 'a`, which means that it'll take a value of the generic type `'a` and return a value of the same generic type `'a`.

In this case, type inferencing kicks in when you *use* it. Because `a` has the type `int list`, and because `List.map` has the signature `('T -> 'U) -> 'T list -> 'U list`, it can infer types from the expression

```
let b = a |> List.map f
```

In this case, the `'T list` argument is `a`, so it has the type `int list`. This means it now knows that `'T` is `int`.

The function passed to `List.map` has the general form `'T -> 'U`, but in this case we pass `f`, which has the form `'a -> 'a`, which is equivalent to `'T -> 'T`. Because of this, the compiler understands that in this case, `'T` and `'U` are the same types.

This means that it can infer that the return type `'U list` must also be `int list`.

Comment: Thanks, I got the fact that f is generic, and this is helpful. But when f  has actually a concrete type, writing the f body with intellisense forces me to specify the concrete type for arg x of f explicitly, which is annoying...

Comment: When I started learning F# (after many years with C#) this annoyed me too, but IME the more you get into the habit of writing idiomatic F# code, the less it turns out to be an issue.

Comment: I toyed a little bit with Nemerle, and it does not exhibit this limitation. The generic inference maybe it is not as broad as in F#...

Comment: How does type inference in F# help me when i write non generic code? If i call an instance method that fixes the type for the argument, F# infers  the type. But not from usage...

Comment: In my experience, it works great when you're calling other F# code, because it all tends to be rather generic. That makes it very flexible. The disadvantage is that it's a bit cumbersome when you have to interact with the BCL (or other object-oriented .NET-code). This is probably the reason why you see most F# code having a thin anti-corruption layer that interfaces with other .NET code, and then a lot of F# code that only talks to other F# code.

Comment: The strangeness comes from another fact: if i make f a method of an object, without type hinting, F# is able to deduce that f is int->int from usage. ONLY if f is declared AFTER the code that calls it. Is this considered as consistent?  this cannot work for local functions...

Comment: Regarding generic code, not all code can be generic. I think a small fraction is generic, code that constitutes some sort of mini framework for the app

Comment: The strangeness comes from another fact: if i make f a method of an object, without type hinting, F# is able to deduce that f is int->int from usage. ONLY if f is declared AFTER the code that calls it. Is this considered as consistent?  this cannot work for local functions or module functions, they cannot be used before they are declared...

Comment: The method behavior you cite happens because inference goes left-to-right top-to-bottom, so it processes the use before the declaration, and the use says `int -> int`. If you declare the method before using it, then it processes the declaration first, and the declaration says `'a -> 'a`.

Comment: Another thing: if I transform f into a lambda and call it directly: List.map (fun x->x )  the inference engine FIXES x as int...

Answer (score 3):

The function `f` is typed `'a -> 'a` because it works at every type, not just `int`:

```
> f "foo";;
val it = "foo" : string
> f 0.8;;
val it = 0.8 : float
```

This an advantage: the generic type `'a -> 'a` gives you the freedom to use `f` when it is safe to do so, as opposed to only at the type `int -> int`.

Answer (score 0):

To add a little something to the fine answers already listed here.

There is one circumstance where you will want to not use the generic inferred type. The generic version of f will be slower than the type specific version. But F# has a keyword for taking care of that for you:

```
let inline f x = x
```

Which tells the compiler to use the type specific version of any operations you apply to x. The inferred type will remain generic. You will only need this in time critical section of code.

As noted elsewhere, the generic inference is a useful thing and you'll probably grow to like it.